# How to retrieve type from the concept?

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

Say I have a concept:

```
template < typename Group  > concept bool GGroup =
    requires() { typename Group::Inner; };
```

How can I retrieve the type `Inner` when using the concept in the short form?

```
void doSomething(const GGroup& group)
{
    // an ugly alternative
    using Inner = typename std::decay_t<decltype(group)>::Inner;

    //// could be something like:
    // using Inner = GGroup::Inner;
    // or
    // using Inner = underlyingtype(GGroup)::Inner;
}
```

Comment: What about using the long form: `template<GGroup Group> void doSomething(const Group& group){ ... Group::Inner ... }`?

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy Yes, but the point is to do it in the shorter form.

Comment: Then you defeat your own purpose. You cannot use the short form (the very point of which is to eliminate an unnecessary reference to the actual type) and refer to the actual type at the same time. For language designers, something like `GGroup::Inner` was not an option because it'd be ambiguous. Consider: if you had `void doSomething(const GGroup& group1, const GGroup& group2)` it'd be equivalent to `template<GGroup Group1, GGroup Group2> void doSomething(const Group1& group1, const Group2& group2)`. Which one would `GGroup` then refer to?

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy Sure, I missed the ambiguity point. The same would be with something like `underlyingtype(GGroup)`. You can post your second comment as an answer, i'll accept it as correct.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy: "*it'd be equivalent to*" Actually, that's the funny thing about concepts TS: it *won't* be equivalent. If you use the same concept twice in a function signature, then Concepts TS *requires* that both variables get the same type. This was done specifically for iterator pairs. That's something [I hope this proposal gets them to change.](http://www.open-std.org/Jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0464r0.html)

Comment: @NicolBolas, Wow! That's counter-intuitive, indeed! I was so cock-sure because I should have never dreamed of such a peculiar constraint. It was all natural to think of concepts as of a natural generalization of `auto`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built-in downside of the short-form of Concepts TS is that you can't just name the typename of a conceptualized parameter. You have to use `decltype` to get it.

So you have a tradeoff: you can either avoid having an explicit `template` declaration at the expense of more `decltype` in your actual code, or you can avoid having `decltype` at the expense of an explicit template declaration.